# Outlook Addin Callback token - getCallbackTokenAsync return null

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins

i just develop an Addin to Outlook and try to get callback token with this function:

```
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true }, function (result)
```

and get this result:

```
Error getting callback token :  {"value":null,"status":"failed","error":{"name":"Internal Error","message":"An internal error has occurred."}}
```

any help... thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. 
My mistake was with the registration of the application on microsoft.
I registered the app with 365 account, while the Outlook runs on an other account of exchange, not the 365 account.
Maybe its could be helpful for someone...